# Removing record from Localstorage proxy in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

So my problem is this. I can remove a record from localstorage proxy just fine the first time. But if I do it again, it gives me an error, where everything in the Store is undefined, like it didnt exist anymore.

```
 onTapRemoveKegelReminder: function(button) {
    console.log(button.getData());
    //Find and delete the button and the record
    var store = Ext.getStore('KegelReminders');
    store.load();
    store.filter('button_id', button.getData());
    var record = store.first();


    console.log(record);
    console.log(button.getData());
    console.log('Remove count'+ store.getCount());


    if (typeof record !== 'undefined'||record!=null ) {
        store.remove(record);
        store.sync();


        console.log('removed record correctly')
        this.trainingCount--;
        var rmButton = this.getKegelExercises().down('#container-' + button.getData());
        this.getKegelExercises().remove(rmButton);

    }
```

But if I restart my application, and then remove again it works fine. I cant seems to remove more than once without having to restart the application.

Answer (score 3):

FYI in case anyone else finds this, removing a record from a Store only removes it from that instance of the store, not from the storage mechanism (for example, localstorage). If you want to do that you have to use the [`erase` method](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-erase) on the model object.

```
store.remove(record); // may not even be necessary
record.erase();
store.sync();
```

Comment: should be mentioned that if you only use erase method your store doesn't become refreshed, means your lists show old data.